# Array of finders for when the previous one fails

Tags: mongodb

I have the following structure for documents:

```
{
  companyId: string,
  language: string,
  country: string,
  template: string
}
```

I need to make a single call to the database to get a document but I have three ways to find it:

```
1 - {companyId: companyId, language: language}
2 - {companyId: companyId, language: languageCompany}
3 - {companyId: 'default', companyId: 'default', country: country}
```

And I want each way to be applied when the previous one has failed.


For example:

Database expample:

```
[{
  companyId: 'companyId1',
  language: 'en',
  country: 'GB',
  template: '....'
}, {
  companyId: 'companyId2',
  language: 'es',
  country: 'ES',
  template: '....'
}, {
  companyId: 'default',
  language: 'default',
  country: 'ES',
  template: '....'
}]
```

Input outputs examples:

```
Input 1
{
  companyId: 'companyId1',
  language: 'en',
  languageCompany: 'en',
  country: 'ES',
}

Output (apply first criteria):
{
  companyId: 'companyId1',
  language: 'en',
  country: 'GB',
  template: '....'
}
```

```
Input 2
{
  companyId: 'companyId2',
  language: 'en',
  languageCompany: 'es',
  country: 'ES',
}

Output (apply second criteria):
{
  companyId: 'companyId1',
  language: 'en',
  country: 'GB',
  template: '....'
}
```

```
Input 3
{
  companyId: 'companyId2',
  language: 'en',
  languageCompany: 'es',
  country: 'ES',
}

Output (apply third criteria):
{
  companyId: 'companyId3',
  language: 'en',
  country: 'ES',
  template: '....'
}
```

**I just want to make a call** It is not worth making the first call and if the second does not return anything, if the third does not return anything.

I let you this litter box in case it goes well for you:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/CksyJE2nJsi

Thanks a lot for help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use facet to run multiple queries

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      query1: [
        {
          $match: {
            companyId: "companyId1",
            language: "en"
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      query2: [
        {
          $match: {
            companyId: "companyId2",
            language: "es"
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      query3: [
        {
          $match: {
            companyId: "default",
            country: "ES"
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      
    }
  }
])
```

This will return an array with all the queries. You have to keep the first one that is not empty.

```
[
  {
    "query1": [
      {
        "companyId": "companyId1",
        "country": "GB",
        "language": "en",
        "template": "...."
      }
    ],
    "query2": [
      {
        "companyId": "companyId2",
        "country": "ES",
        "language": "es",
        "template": "...."
      }
    ],
    "query3": [
      {
        "companyId": "default",
        "country": "ES",
        "language": "default",
        "template": "...."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/k3IAfiLi2Lf

In case your db had this data:

```
[
  {
    companyId: "othercompanyId1",
    language: "en",
    country: "GB",
    template: "...."
  },
  {
    companyId: "othercCompanyId2",
    language: "es",
    country: "ES",
    template: "...."
  },
  {
    companyId: "default",
    language: "default",
    country: "ES",
    template: "...."
  }
]
```

This would return information in the third query:

```
[
  {
    "query1": [],
    "query2": [],
    "query3": [
      {
        "companyId": "default",
        "country": "ES",
        "language": "default",
        "template": "...."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: it's good but it will be better if it stop when first matched